# Can i get the neareast location covered with a certain perimeter

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation, geocoding

I need some help in geolocation or google maps, is it possible to get all the nearest store which is 
covered by a desired perimeter. what i want to achieve is that when i am online in a 
certain area and i want to know what are the nearest store available in my location,.Is 
this possible to achieve in geolocation or in a google maps.I want to integrate this in my web development.

I have the list of the store and their addresses and also i have the lon and lat coordinates.
of a certain store.i want to show them up in google map with markers as their indicator which is covered to a desired perimeter or a certain range.

Many Thanks!

Comment: The generic answer is "yes", mobile phones and other location aware devices do this all the time.  Do you have control of the list of stores?  Do you just want to use the Google Local API, plus geolocation API, to find instances?  Please add information to your question.

Comment: @Tony mIller, Hi actually i have no idea yet for this which should i use the Google Local API plus google geolocation API,..by the way i want to integrate this in my web development...yes i have the list of stores,..if it is possible to get their instances.Thank you.

Comment: @Tony miller, can i achieve this in google map to show markers of the store which is nearest to my location ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember, "Geolocation is the identification of the real-world geographic location of an object" such as a business or a house. - [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geolocation)

Also, if you have the lat/lon coordinates of two points, it is trivial to [determine the distance](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) between them.

So, if you have a list of geolocations for certain points (stores, houses, mountain peaks, whatever) you can determine the distance and then filter to show only the ones within a certain range that you set.

@Tony Miller is right, you need to provide a little more information about what you are looking for.

Comment: Hi jeffrey, Thank you for the reply,is there other way to achieve this?i mean without using geolocation...the only thing that what i want is to show in the map of all stores with in my certain area where i was online..i have the list of stores and addresses but how could i show them, which one of them are nearest to my location.

Comment: Hi jeffrey, how can i show the store using the marker in google map

Comment: @mathiascolebar I can't think of any way to automatically do it without the geolocation.  Remember, a store is a physical location and a geocode attempts to represent that location on a map.  The latitude and longitude are used to best approximate a location on a map.  That's what the geocode is.  If you only have a fixed number of store locations, you could manually mark them on a google map.  Doing that will assign a geolocation to the marker that you drop so that the location can be used next time.

Comment: ,Okay i just have 5 stores and with their lon and lat...how can i specify the perimeter so that they will show up in the map.Thank you:)

Comment: If you're just trying to draw a map with 5 markers, one for each store, and have the map show them all, please check out this link: https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3

Comment: @mathiascolebar If you were to revise your original question with some real (or sample) data it would enable you to get a better answer.

Comment: @Jeffrey, I do apologize for that,but i just added some information..I think store locator is suite for my needs.let me check this first.,i will write back both of you.Thank you:)

Comment: @TonyMiller,can we put range of this or i mean just like a radar that if i am in a certain location and if i will range to 200meters away from my location if the stores is covered with that 200meters it will show up in google map,is this possible?Thank you in advance:)

Comment: @TonyMiller this is what i want the store locator.:)